# Flutter row, align items individually in cross axis

Tags: flutter, widget, vertical-alignment

In a row widget, with the `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` property, all the widgets inside of the row will be vertically centred inside the Row, as expected.

But how do I do if I want only one of them aligned for exmample to the start, something like the picture below:

[image]

I can think of some ways to do it, like adding a `Column` in the last widget, and play with the main axis aligment, `Expanded`...etc etc but seems like a lot of boilerplate code for such a simple output, ther might be out there a simpler and more elegant way to achieve this??

Comment: That's not possible without wrapping widget4 inside another column

Comment: yeah...it might be so im afraid...but let's give it some time in case someone else comes up with an interesting approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap widget 4 in a `Container` and set the height as widget 3 and add `Alignment.topCenter`

Comment: yeah that is a good one, slightly simpler than adding a Column for example, thanks

Comment: you're hard-coding the height?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, stumbled across this and found a solution.

Wrap widgets 3 and 4 in another `Row` and set the inner `Row` to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`.

```
Row(
  children: [
    LargeWidget('w1'),
    LargeWidget('w2'),
    Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        LargeWidget('w3'),
        SmallWidget('w4'),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

This frees you from having to know the height of each widget.